# Views conditional referenced field depending on user taxonomy term

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, entities, users

I have a Content-type that an admin can assign it's nodes to other users, and users are separated by their taxonomy term.

I'm using Entity Reference field to reference the user and overriding the output of it using views to reduce the user list to my preference.

This is how user referencing works:

- Each user has a taxonomy term (e.g. Editor, Moderator, BadAss,
  UberSuperEditor, etc...)
- Each term parents more than 100 of users.

I want the Admin to be able to filter the output of users based on their taxonomy before selecting and assigning the node to them.

I want to make a view and make a conditional relation based on the "Term" selected then show the related users of that term.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your explanation is describing the [Reference Field Option Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit) module:

> This module allows reference fields of several types to have their
>   widgets' available options limited by the values of other fields in
>   the current entity.
>
> This is best illustrated by examples:
>
> Example 1: countries and cities Suppose you want to label articles (or
>   products, or businesses, etc) by both city and country so both can be
>   used for filtering and searching. You could use a hierarchical
>   taxonomy with city terms as children of country terms, but that
>   doesn't make sense when you come to set up Views filters.
>
> With this module, create two separate taxonomies for country and city
>   (or content types, or whatever entity you want to use). Then add a
>   reference field so that each city points to its country: eg, the term
>   'Paris' has a reference to 'France'.
>
> Then when editing an article, selecting 'France' in the country field
>   will cause the city field to update to show only cities in France.

Give it a try and let me know how it works. The module currently supports Taxonomy terms and Entity Reference Widgets.

Comment: Thanks tenken for the hint, I'll look it up right now and let you know if it works

Comment: well its not working, because one is a term and the other is a user field

Comment: hmm a `user field` in the Field UI or an `entity reference` to a user? It sounds like it should let you target User references from this old issue queue item https://www.drupal.org/node/1505176

Comment: Okay its exactly the same issue as mine, and it's not fixed, it just got closed with no activity ;( thanks for the effort btw